# Do you capitalise words like 'Liberalism'?

Tags: capitalization

Do you capitalise words like 'Liberalism', 'Communism', 'Socialism'?

I'm presuming that such words are proper nouns because they are the specific names of ideologies. If they are not capitalised, why not?

And if they *are* capitalised, are words like mathematics capitalised? I am led to believe they are not unless they are the name of a specific course subject like 'Maths 101', but isn't mathematics the proper noun of a specific concept?

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: Depends on the specific meaning and the context.

Comment: Mathematics is not capitalised, because there isn't a specific movement which endorses it, (although there may have been in ancient times).

Comment: If you like, you can capitalize any word. It's pronounced the same whether it's capitalized or not.

Comment: Colleges, schools, etc, may capitalise the names of academic subjects when they are the names of departments, but it is an error (often committed) to capitalise them in ordinary discussion, e.g. "I am interested in Geography"

Comment: I have on a number of occasions seen articles that talked about "small c communism" vs "large C Communism".  In certain contexts the capitalization conveys a specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in usage depends on whether the "-ism" is related to an established organisation or well-defined movement, or whether it is related to a more informal or organic grouping.

For example: in the UK we have a Conservative party. Thus you can have a **Conservative** estimate of the state of the economy which is one made and/or promoted by the Conservative party and a **conservative** estimate of the state of the economy which takes a moderate view of the performance.

These are usually two different things, If the Conservatives are in power the Conservative estimate will be more bullish than the conservative estimate but when they are not in power it will be more pessimistic.

Similarly In the US you can have **democratic** principles and **Democratic** principles, the former being the general principles underpinning a democratic state and the latter being the more or less formally expressed principles expressed and promoted by the Democratic Party.

You can also have **republican** beliefs and **Republican** beliefs. The former are beliefs held by people who are opposed to hereditary power, particularly monarchy, and the latter are the beliefs formulated, expressed and promoted by the Republican Party.

Answer (score 0):

Religions and nationalities are proper nows. Political leanings are common nouns.

*Maths 101* is a course title. Titles are proper nouns.

Proceed accordingly.

Comment: But there is a difference between "communist" and "Communist".

Comment: In the UK we have a Conservative party. Thus you can have a Conservative estimate of the state of the economy which is one made and/or promoted by the Conservative party and a conservative estimate of the state of the economy which takes a moderate view of the performance. These are usually two different things, If the Conservatives are in power the Conservative estimate will be more bullish than the conservative estimate but when they are not in power it will be more pessimistic. Similarly In the US you can have Democratic or Republican principles and democratic or republican principles